# How the view for second tab is loaded in iPhoneCoreDataRecipie project provided in ADC library

Tags: iphone

I was going through the core Data recipie example application provided by apple. I saw they are using TabBarController. For first View controller I can see it being assigned to listviewController but What I did not understand is where are they assigning the view for weight converter. Like How is that being initialized, so when you clik on second tab, respective view is being invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it...

Its being done setting the view Controller.